# Is request from client's PC or my database server?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, oracle-apex

I need to develop a database project with APEX and Google map service. I notice there is limit for Google map service.

I would assume if I write javascript code in APEX and send request to Google such as loading a map, the request is sent from client browser directly to Google map server, not from my database server to Google map server, so my application won't break the service limit. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "break the service limit."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the request is originating from - each request contains the API key which identifies your application(might have changed since the last time I took a look). So be it coming from the Database service or the js-client - it doesn't matter.

Your app *will* break the service limit, the moment it crosses over the quota.

Comment: Hi, Sathya: Thanks for your reply. What if I do not set API key for client pages, Would this avoid the problem?  Thanks.  Sam

Comment: @lxiscas considering Google mandates that you use API key for requset, it'll only cause further problems

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother coding this as there Is a google map plugin available for 4.1.  Apex-plugins.com

Comment: Nice parked domain. Not an appropriate answer to the question asked, anyway